# How to get a request user query without hitting DB each time in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I built some Blog API but I've got an issue.

In the serializer, there is a method field that returns request user has liked the post or not. The problem is this field hits the user DB each time a post returns, which means if 1000 posts are returned, user DB would be hit 1000 times.
 How can I avoid this? The first idea was to assign the request user to something like a global variable, but I don't know how to.

this is serializer

```py
class DashboardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(allow_null=True, use_url=True)
    likes_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    user_has_liked = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    owner = UserField(read_only=True)
    comments = CommentsField(read_only=True, many=True, source='two_latest_comments')
    comments_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'owner', 'likes_count', 'user_has_liked',
                  'image', 'video', 'tags', 'get_elapsed_time_after_created',
                  'comments', 'comments_count']
        ordering = ['created_at']

    def get_likes_count(self, instance):
        return instance.likes.count()

    def get_user_has_liked(self, instance):
        request = self.context.get('request')
     ***return instance.likes.filter(pk=request.user.pk).exists()***
     *******request.user.pk hits the DB.*********


    def get_comments_count(self, instance):
        return instance.comments.count()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean, every single time? How could it not?

Comment: What query are you talking about? Why do you say "request.user.pk hits the DB"? It looks to me like `instance.likes.filter(pk=request.user.pk).exists()` is producing a query every time this method is called. The `request.user` is fetched once for every request in the AuthenticationMiddleware.

Comment: I mean if there are a thousand posts to be returned, the method searches the user pk in DB each time get_user_has_liked is called. Doesn't it?

Comment: No. If the serializer is used on a list endpoint, there will be one query per user. But it doesn't matter how many posts there are. From the name of the serializer it seems like it isn't for a list view, so it should just be a single extra query for the whole endpoint, to find if any posts exist for that user. And this type of query is very fast as it can use an index and just return true if it finds one without searching any further.

Comment: I'm reading between the lines a bit since your question is vague, but is this serializer used for a post list of some kind? If so, then yes, it'll be called for each post, and there's no way around that other than caching the values somehow, which runs the risk of your data being out of date. But as mentioned, these queries are very fast and shouldn't be a problem... unless you've benchmarked and have found that this API is unbearably slow?

Comment: How is `two_latest_comments` defined? Isn't it hitting the db for instance as well in the loop?

Comment: Tom Carrick No It's not. It works fast. I just wanna know there is a simple way to do it. Thank you so much.

Comment: mfrackowiak/ Yeap it is. But every post has its own comments. But unlike it, requesting user pk is shared, and That's why I wanna know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) and [`Exists` subqyery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) on the queryset that you are passing to the serializer, and then adjust the fields:

serializer call:

```
    queryset = ...  # your queryset
    user_commented = Comment.objects.filter(
        blog_id=OuterRef("pk"),
        user_id=request.user.pk,
    )
    data = DashboardSerializer(instance=queryset.annotate(
        likes_count=Count("likes"),
        comments_count=Count("comments"),
        user_has_liked=Exists(user_commented),
    )
```

serializer:

```
class DashboardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(allow_null=True, use_url=True)
    likes_count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    user_has_liked = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
    owner = UserField(read_only=True)
    comments = CommentsField(read_only=True, many=True, source='two_latest_comments')
    comments_count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'owner', 'likes_count', 'user_has_liked',
                  'image', 'video', 'tags', 'get_elapsed_time_after_created',
                  'comments', 'comments_count']
        ordering = ['created_at']
```